# How can I prevent Gmail from formatting our order numbers as IP addresses

Tags: gmail, text-formatting

We send out e-mails to our customers containing an order number. Unfortunately Gmail thinks these numbers are IP addresses and turns them into hyperlinks:

In a regular e-mail-client:

> Your order number is: 08.12.2013-61

In Gmail:

```
Your order number is: <a href="tel:08.12.2013-16" value="+49812201316" target="_blank">08.12.2013-61</a>
```

I don't want to Gmail to add this HTML tag to the e-mail.

Is there anything I can do when creating or sending the e-mail to prevent this formatting error?

**Edit**
There was a discussion if Google formats the number into a phone number or an IP number. That's not really important to me. It's neither type of number. I want to prevent Google from auto formatting our order number in any way.

Comment: I'm... not sure what is the difference between the two..?

Comment: Are you sure it’s thinking they phone numbers and not IP addresses? Are you sure about the content and formatting of the resulting HTML that Gmail auto-adds?

Comment: @Synetech : if the `tel:` part in the hyperlink is added by gmail, then it must definitely think they are phone numbers, don't you think so ?

Comment: Are you sending from Gmail?

Comment: @Levans, but the `tel:` part was *not in the [original post](http://superuser.com/revisions/685692/1)*; you added that. Unless she reports back with the exact link that is added, we can only conjecture. The order number doesn’t really look like either an IP address or a phone number, it only looks *kind of* like both, so Gmail’s heuristic is throwing false-positives. Regardless, the answer would likely apply to all text that Gmail auto-interprets and auto-formats.

Comment: The "tel:" part was part of my original post. That's the whole point of my question. My post was edited incorrectly by someone.

@Franck Dernoncourt, no we are not sending from Gmail, but from our own mail server to Gmail.

Comment: Does your recipient use the Google Voice Chrome Extension? Or Skype? Or any of a number of extensions that attempts to convert what looks like phone numbers into clickable links?

Comment: I tried sending myself the same message from and to gmail - both as an html and plain text message. The order number was not converted in either situation. This seems to be more of a client-side issue than an issue with gmail itself.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as "Unclear what you're asking". There are several comments asking for clarification, which has not been forthcoming. Without more information all we're getting is conjecture. If we get the details needed to answer this can be re-opened.

Answer (score 2):

At this time Gmail web UI only converts text that looks like a URL to hyperlinks. If a serial number that use periods as separators if being changed it's more likely that it's done by an add-on or extension, as was already mentioned in the comments by @AI_E.

The plug-in could be the Google's audio and video plug-in that is required by some browsers to use Google Voice or Hangouts video calls.

---

**References**

- [IP addresses considered as telephone numbers, linking to Google Voice - Gmail Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/AldnlntO-ck)
- [Click to call phone numbers - Gmail Offial Blog](http://gmailblog.blogspot.mx/2011/03/click-to-call-phone-numbers.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can add a [soft hyphen](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ad/index.htm) character. So, I would suggest using the following HTML code in your email body:

```
Your order number is: 08.&#173;12.&#173;2013-&#173;61
```

Comment: Just make sure your email has the text-only version as well, where the soft hyphen is not present, because the customers that have their email  clients set to plain text only will see it exactly like that, with “&#173;”.